# What doctrines distinguish meaningfully between YEC distant starlight creation models and sky-dome-ism?

Tags: creation, young-earth-creation, geocentrism

With regards to doctrines of creation, it appears to be the case that most Christian denominations (minus some predominantly OEC belief systems) assert that Creation (of worlds, stars and galaxies) "ended" (See Genesis 2:1). Under various such frameworks, distant starlight is accommodated by saying that it was created in transit, or may have [traveled much faster](https://answersingenesis.org/astronomy/starlight/does-distant-starlight-prove-the-universe-is-old/) in the past than it does now, or may travel at different speeds depending on its direction, etc.

The debunked idea that the ancient Israelites and prophets considered the sky to be a solid dome with stars painted or bolted onto it was based on a [mistranslation](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/justin-taylor/stop-saying-ancient-israelites-believed-sky-big-solid-dome-heavenly-sea/) of the word the KJV authors rendered "firmament". It seems likely that other misconceptions of cosmology abound. Nonetheless, the idea circulating in blogs and literature provided abundant (but untrue) fodder for mockery against Abrahamic religions and against the faithful in the Bible.

Is not the theory of starlight created in transit, or whatever might be the most observationally accommodating model positing that celestial bodies are for signs and seasons to this world only, functionally equivalent to a great grandfather clock mounted on a solid dome ceiling over our Earth?
If the sole purpose of remote stars and galaxies is for our sightseeing and timekeeping (citing Genesis 1:14, admittedly a very geocentric model of the universe), would not a high resolution digital light projector shining on some cosmic sheet pinned to the living room ceiling work just as well?
Given the expense (in atoms, photons, planning, intricacy, variety, time) required to create such a vast array of real stars, galaxies and planets, does God intend to miss out on the economy of such additional creations, by making them "for display only"? Display is doubtless a useful purpose, but a bare minimum of hundreds of billions of trillions of real stars seems like overkill as a display for the benefit of just one planet that has, in its short existence, housed only a few dozen billion persons according to prevalent estimates.

What is an overview of young earth creationist responses to this potential criticism, from various Christian denominations that hold a doctrine on the subject?
Specifically, that any model that accommodates distant stars and galaxies by treating them as "for display only" reduces to the same functional argument of utility as could be answered by a solid sky dome with gears and cantilevers attached to painted glow-in-the-dark stars, or of a futuristic light show projector and planetarium screen, however detailed and sophisticated they might be?

Comment: To be fair, the "mistranslation" is due to an imposition of the (incorrect) beliefs of the time. Sort of like how the word (correctly!) translated as "[unicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rhinoceros)" is mistranslated as "wild ox" in modern translations. Also, your list of alternative explanations is conspicuously missing [anisotropic speed-of-light](https://answersingenesis.org/astronomy/starlight/distant-starlight-thesis/).

Comment: @Matthew An imposition of incorrect beliefs implies that the resulting translation is likely improper. It wasn't my purpose to give an overview of all the different theories, and I believe the already-stated variability in the speed of light is sufficient to represent other similar theories.

Comment: Right; I'm not saying "mistranslation" isn't the right term, I'm just mentioning how it happened.

Comment: @Matthew I have edited the OP to include mention of the anisotropic speed of light theory.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start here:

> the idea circulating in blogs and literature provided abundant (but untrue) fodder for mockery against Abrahamic religions and against the faithful in the Bible

Ah, delicious irony. Meanwhile, those same scoffers believe in "dark matter" (which has never been observed and is suspiciously ad hoc) and "inflation" (which is absurdly ad hoc and for which no mechanism is known), because without such rescuing devices, *their* cosmology has serious flaws. Indeed, it has serious flaws in general, because very distant galaxies are supposed to "look younger", and they don't (thank you JWST!). The latter in particular suggests that the alleged correlation between how far light travels to arrive at Earth and how "out of date" what we observe via that same light is not correlated in the manner supposed.

> Is not the theory of starlight created in transit, or whatever might be the most observationally accommodating model positing that celestial bodies are for signs and seasons to this world only, functionally equivalent to a great grandfather clock mounted on a solid dome ceiling over our Earth? If the sole purpose of remote stars and galaxies is for our sightseeing and timekeeping (citing Genesis 1:14, admittedly a very geocentric model of the universe), would not a high resolution digital light projector shining on some cosmic sheet pinned to the living room ceiling work just as well?

Perhaps, but that's full of some mighty big assumptions. In particular, "the heavens declare the glory of God" (Psalm 19:1). Would "a high resolution digital light projector shining on some cosmic sheet pinned to the living room ceiling" declare God's glory as effectively? Maybe, but God wanted to do things the way He did.

Mind, there are serious objections to the "light created in transit" hypothesis, in particular, that God would need to have Created light suggesting the existence of things that never existed.

It seems more likely that [the speed of light is anisotropic](https://answersingenesis.org/astronomy/starlight/distant-starlight-thesis/), with Earth being in a privileged position. This would not only explain how we can see things that are very distant, but also why there is little difference between things close by and things that are very, very distant. (Note that this seems to be consistent with relativity and does not have the problems that variable speed-of-light has.)

> Given the expense (in atoms, photons, planning, intricacy, variety, time) required to create such a vast array of real stars, galaxies and planets, does God intend to miss out on the economy of such additional creations, by making them "for display only"? Display is doubtless a useful purpose, but a bare minimum of hundreds of billions of trillions of real stars seems like overkill as a display for the benefit of just one planet that has, in its short existence, housed only a few dozen billion persons according to prevalent estimates.

Again, "the heavens declare the glory of God". What is "overkill" to the all-powerful God? What need has He to be economical? Doesn't such "excess" speak more completely to His glory?

A human circa 2020 might be able to conceive of the technology to create "a solid sky dome with gears and cantilevers attached to painted glow-in-the-dark stars, or of a futuristic light show projector and planetarium screen". It would be impressive, but impressive in the manner of the Great Pyramid, or the Burj Khalifa. [Douglas Adams](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Magrathea) and [Freeman Dyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere) conceived of such capabilities. Creating *entire galaxies* is more impressive by many orders of magnitude!

Comment: I agree that dark matter and inflationary theories are suspiciously ad hoc, however is not anisotropy similarly ad hoc, designed to favor a geocentrist model of the universe?
If anisotropy were real, could we not observe some form of parallax or fluctuation in this phenomenon? Seeing the same pattern of special pleading and exhausting numerous theories in some versions of Christianity is concerning, even more so than attempts to rescue known-problematic secular precepts. The JWST findings are an awesome testament to the unique truth of Christianity.

Comment: @pygosceles, yes and no. You have, in a sense, hit on the difficulty of choosing between competing hypotheses, which is why it's important to consider other information (e.g. Scripture, other evidence that the universe is no more than thousands of years old). In particular, homogeneity of the CMB argues for one of inflation or anisotropic speed-of-light (ASOL) being correct. Lack of differentiation between nearby and distant galaxies argues for ASOL or non-constant speed-of-light or something along those lines.

Comment: As to whether ASOL can be demonstrated... I'm not aware of any proposed experiment which could do so, and my understanding is that relativity would preclude doing so. There is plenty of secular research on whether ASOL could be demonstrated. However, your Question seemed to focus on "why *not* a sky dome?", which I hope I've answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Uniform CMB can also be explained by infinite extent of the universe.

Comment: I'm not sure I or my acquaintances who criticize us on this point will be satisfied by saying that it's essentially just more intricate and extravagant than any illusory mechanism we can conceive of. This raises other concerns, such as, Is God wasteful? It is not as though appearance is everything, even if distant stars are real and the light we see from them is genuine (which I assume all reasonable people accept that they are).
I am still looking for something that breaks the vicious cycle of ad hoc.
Could you perhaps identify in your answer which precept seems to need so much rescuing?